Trouble locating the INSTALLLOCATION in msiexec docs
I am currently following the msiexec documentaion for mongodb and I am having trouble finding the INSTALLLOCATION in the docs. The command is show below
msiexec.exe /l*v mdbinstall.log  /qb /i mongodb-windows-x86_64-7.0-signed.msi ^
            INSTALLLOCATION="C:\MongoDB\Server\7.0\"

I am new to using msicexec and was familarising my self with the docs to see what each section dose, yet I have no luck finding INSTALLLOCATION. I have found the TARGETDIR in the properties section of the microsoft documentaion, but nothing on INSTALLLOCATION.
Is there anyone that can help with locating this in the documentaion?

INSTALLLOCATION isn't built-in to the Windows Installer. That's why you won't find it in the docs. It is a common name for a configurable Directory along with INSTALLDIR and INSTALLFOLDER.
